# Using Leaf, the else condition isn't properly executed though the if one is

Tags: if-statement, vapor, leaf

I have a simple Leaf template that I'd like to display Hello World in.

```
#if(false) {
<title> All hail Apodron.</title>
} #else {
<title> Hello World </title>
}
```

the page has no title and displays as:

`#else {Helloward}`

However, if I change this to:

```
#if(true) {
<title> All hail Apodron.</title>
} #else {
<title> Hello World </title>
}
```

then the title does display, but the page STILL shows up as:

`#else {Helloward}`

I also tried various syntaxes, such as:

`##else {
    <title> Hello World </title>
    }` and `#else() {
    <title> Hello World </title>
    }` or even `##else() {
    <title> Hello World </title>
    }`

This seemed very basic, and I believe I followed the [documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/leaf/leaf/#leafs-built-in-tags).

Comment: Does the vapor console offer any helpful message?

Comment: Nothing beyond: `Server starting on http://localhost:8080`. Is there a more verbose mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your problem is Leaf is expecting `else`, but are using `#else`. So changing your template to this should fix it:

```
#if(false) {
  <title> All hail Apodron.</title>
} else {
  <title> Hello World </title>
}
```

Here is the relevant [documentation](https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/leaf/overview/#conditions).